# Kivy TreeView: collapse button really small on android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm using `TreeView` to build an app, and it renders fine when testing on my laptop but the little buttons to collapse/uncollapse tree nodes are tiny on my phone (see the tiny arrow next to `Group 1` in the image).  I've looked for an attribute or property in `TreeView` that I could set, but nothing seems to help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because using an invalid [sizing units](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions). I guess you either used `width = 100` or `width = 100px` or similar thing. Mostly phones and tablets, but even other displays handle such things a little bit differently.

To fix that use `dp` unit described in the link provided above:

**.py:**

```
width = '100dp'
```

**.kv:**

```
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
width: dp(100)
```

To test how the layout looks at such devices use [`screen`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.screen.html) module or the commands mentioned in `kivy.metrics` documentation to manually modify DPI of your application. Screen is more powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the screen module seems super useful!  It only seems to work for old screen resolutions though; any idea on how to run it with, say, the galaxy s6?  I'll see if I can find something about assigning a size with TreeView, but I haven't found any attribute yet...

Comment: It's only about three or four properties you need to set. Look into the [source of screen](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/modules/screen.py) and add a new one there. You need to know resolution, dpi and density of the screen (internet).